# Modularising projects with Maven

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee

I have an existing project that I am going to separate into three project. Let say the existing project is named A. I want to extract the logic that I could use into two other projects B and C. So now project A only depends on B and C and project A have the code special for that particular project. However, both B and C need a User class in order to work (security). At the moment I use the same User class every where. Is it possible to use the same User class in each project, and if so how? Where would you keep it? Does it sounds like a bad idea that different projects use the same User class? If I need to deal with multiple User classes, how where should I convert between them?

Comment: Don't duplicate User class. Make a project D if you have to, and put user there.

Answer (score 2):

The best aproach is to create a multi module build which looks like this:

```
 project-app (pom.xml)
  +-- project-A (pom.xml) dep: project-B,project-C
  +-- project-B (pom.xml) dep: user
  +-- project-C (pom.xml)
  +-- user (pom.xml)
```

That will solve your requirements. But it can be that your development is going beyond which means that you want to create an other project, let us call it **project-new-app**, which needs the user class as well. This will indicate that you have to go into an other direction like. Create a separate project for the user part:

```
user (pom.xml)
```

And now the **project-new-app** can use the user part as a simple dependency:

```
project-new-app (pom.xml) dep: user
  +--- maybe more..
```

and afterwards all your projects can have a depenendency on that **user** project. So the original **project-app**:

```
 project-app (pom.xml)
  +-- project-A (pom.xml) dep: project-B,project-C
  +-- project-B (pom.xml) dep: user
  +-- project-C (pom.xml)
```

Comment: Thanks, but when you use JPA for instance you normally add annotations and relations to other domain objects. Let say that some of the domain objects were in other projects. Would you only create a user interface in the user project and then do the actual implementation of the user in the project for your new app?

Answer (score 0):

To further extend Karl-Heinz' answer:

```
project-app (pom.xml)
+-- project-A : dep: project-B
+-- project-B : dep: user
+-- project-C : dep: user-impl1
+-- project-D : dep: user-impl2
+-- user-api :  contains either or both:
                 a) a User interface,
                 b) an AbstractUser class to be extended
+-- user-impl1 : some implementation of the User class
+-- user-impl2 : some other implementation of the User class
```

In the example above, I'll leave it up to you to figure out where you'd like to tie your dependencies to `user-impl1` and `user-impl2`.

Make sure your code works with a more generic implementation of the `User` class/interface and your code refactoring should work just fine.

By any means, ***do not*** copy the User class around your modules. Soon enough you'll find it will give you more headaches than you've thought, if you use copies.